# Changing default profile from A2DP to HSP on every new bluetooth headset using pipewire/wireplumber

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, pipewire

I want to dynamically ensure every bluetooth headset are using HSP audio profile. I can easily set it manually but that has to be done actively for every device.

I have attempted to change default profiles in 50-bluez-config.lua and also looked through various other configs and policies. But with no success.

Writing a udev rule does not seem to be useful either since I could not see how it could work dynamically.